# Python Dict to CSV: Expected an Indented Block

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, indentation

Trying to write output to a csv and getting an indentation error. I'm sure it's a stupid mistake but I can't figure out why it's being thrown.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import copy
import os
import sys
import glob

#get current working dir, set count, and select file delimiter
os.chdir('/Users/Briana/Documents/Misc./PythonTest')

#parses through files and saves to a dict
series = {}
for fn in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(fn) as f:
        series[fn] = (1 for line in f if line.strip() and not line.startswith('#')) 

print series

#save the dictionary with key/val pairs to a csv
with open('seriescount.csv', 'wb') as f: 
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, series.keys()) #error thrown here
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(sum(names.values()))
```

Full traceback:

```
Fri Jul 24 03:13 PM [Briana PythonTest] (dev) $ ./SeriesCount.py 
File "./SeriesCount.py", line 22 
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, series.keys()) 
                                       ^ 
    IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: I don't get any error, did you mix tab and spaces? what is your traceback?

Comment: It should tell you what line is the problem. Check the line above the one it tells you that is the issue. Also, note that for each indent the safest way is to put 4 spaces and never use a tab.

Comment: nope, I formatted it exactly how I have it on my machine. Here's my terminal output: Fri Jul 24 03:01 PM [Briana PythonTest] (dev) $ python SeriesCount.py 
  File "SeriesCount.py", line 22
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, series.keys())
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: It's on the 2nd to last line, I know what line is the problem, I'm just not sure why. I'm not mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: Does you code look exactly as posted?

Comment: Try changing the parenthetical on that line to (f, fieldnames = series.keys()) https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=dictwriter#csv.DictWriter

Comment: I get a `NameError: name 'names' is not defined` on the last line -- so it doesn't seem like your actual code.

Comment: Just tried it, I still get the same output

Comment: Please add the full traceback you're getting to your question.

Comment: Sorry: 

Fri Jul 24 03:13 PM [Briana PythonTest] (dev) $ ./SeriesCount.py 
  File "./SeriesCount.py", line 22
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, series.keys())
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Attempting to add a traceback in the code but not getting any output?

Comment: Try deleting that space after the : on the previous line

Comment: It looks like there's a space on stackoverflow, but in my code there's no space, unfortunately...

Comment: I tried it on another computer and got the same error, so I know it's not just my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have submitted your code here *exactly* as it is on your machine, it appears that there *are* spaces and tabs mixed together.  If I copy the code as it appears in your question, it is indented, consistently, with spaces; however, if I press "edit" and then examine the code, the first 21 lines are indented with spaces, and lines 22-24 are indented with tabs.  The code below fixes this error; take care to copy it exactly as it appears here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import copy
import os
import sys
import glob

#get current working dir, set count, and select file delimiter
os.chdir('/Users/Briana/Documents/Misc./PythonTest')

#parses through files and saves to a dict
series = {}
for fn in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(fn) as f:
        series[fn] = (1 for line in f if line.strip() and not line.startswith('#')) 

print series

#save the dictionary with key/val pairs to a csv
with open('seriescount.csv', 'wb') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, series.keys()) #error thrown here
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(sum(names.values()))
```

There are three common causes for `IndentationError: expected an indented block`:

- Neglecting, or forgetting, to indent at all
- Commenting out part of an indented block
- Mixing tabs and spaces in indentation